# Display the first clause value, then the second one

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get this query to display first the where clause value, and, if the first where clause is empty, go for the second one. In case both are not empty, it should only look for the first clause.

```
SELECT id 
FROM mdl_course_categories
Where id = '{Section}' or id = '{semester}'
```

This code is showing both data section and semester, but I'd like it to show the section first, and then the semester. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the results?  Have you tried adding an `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: no i just want to display the value of only one where clause if section is available then do not look for semester

Comment: what is id? a text field? how can it have both values at the same time?

Comment: So sort the results, then add a `LIMIT` clause?

Comment: i am using this for ajax reload to change value select type field

Comment: Can you shows us some example data and the expected result you want from your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to add an `order by` clause:

```
order by (id = '{Section}') desc,
         (id = '{Semester}') desc
```

In MySQL, the boolean true is treated as `1` and false as `0`.

EDIT:

If you only one one row, where the row would be the first match and then the second, then just add a `limit` after the `order by`:

```
order by (id = '{Section}') desc,
         (id = '{Semester}') desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to select those separately.

P.S. Why are you selecting id if you are using it win WHERE?